# Making div fade in and out when scrolling

Tags: javascript

I have a div that is set to:

```
{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

This div is also at the top of the page.
I want to make it so that as I scroll down (and away from the div), it slowly fades in, and when I scroll back up it fades out.

How would I do this?

Comment: I would suggest adding the jquery library and using the animate function.  It animates between styles. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp

Comment: @StephenFlynn -- Don't use W3Schools as the first source of reference, as their articles are often outdated. Refer to jQuery's official documentation or MDN (for HTML, CSS and JavaScript) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.body.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
                                    let faceLayer = document.getElementById('your_id');
                                    faceLayer.style.opacity = Math.abs(Math.max(faceLayer.getBoundingClientRect().top, 0) / faceLayer.clientHeight).
                                })
```

Answer (score 1):

You may refer following code snippet. The point I am trying to make is in the script tag at the bottom just added the window scroll function which sets the opacity to your entire window of desired height in your css class ".top". So when you try to scroll in and out it will dynamically add an animation effect to your window.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      height: 1000px;
    }
    
    .top {
      margin: 0;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #aaa;
      height: 300px;
      opacity: 1;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'helvetica';
      font-size: 80px;
      font-weight: 100;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .title {
      position: absolute;
      top: 60%;
      left: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="title">Fade Away</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
  });
</script>
```